# Как сгруппировать массив из хешей по ключу?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть массив, состоящий из хешей:

```
[
  {:car=>["BMW", "Mersedes", "Audi"]},
  {:car=>["Renault", "Ferrari", "Nissan"]},
  {:car=>["VW"]},
  {:country=>["Russia", "Japan", "USA"]},
  {:country=>["China", "Nigeria", "Egypt"]},
  {:city=>["Moscow", "Tokyo", "Amsterdam"]}
]
```

Нужно сгруппировать хэшы по ключу, типа:

```
[
  {:car=>[["BMW", "Mersedes", "Audi"], ["Renault", "Ferrari", "Nissan"], ["VW"]]},
  {:country=>[["Russia", "Japan", "USA"], ["China", "Nigeria", "Egypt"]]},
  {:city=>["Moscow", "Tokyo", "Amsterdam"]}
]
```

т.е. объединить массивы с одинаковым ключом.

Comment: да, в дальнейшем мне нужно будет работать с массивом

Comment: Тут в ответе верно отметили, что у вас с уровнями массивов нестыковка. Что в `:car` и `:country` у вас значения собраны в массив, а в `:city` значение почему-то без дополнительной обёртки. Правда, наружная структура от этого менее странной не становится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).map{ |k, g| {k => g.map(&:last)} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
cars = [
  {:car=>["BMW", "Mersedes", "Audi"]},
  {:car=>["Renault", "Ferrari", "Nissan"]},
  {:car=>["VW"]},
  {:country=>["Russia", "Japan", "USA"]},
  {:country=>["China", "Nigeria", "Egypt"]},
  {:city=>["Moscow", "Tokyo", "Amsterdam"]}
]

result = cars.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |el, hash|
  hash[el.keys.first] << el[el.keys.first]
end.map { |k, v| { k => v } }
```

Comment: @D-side Спасибо, поправил!

Comment: Угу. Только возвращаемое значение всё ещё хэш, а должно быть -- массив.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. Единственное, каждый элемент массива является массивом массива, если критически важно в случае :city, чтобы получился обычный массив, необходимо пробежаться еще одним map-ом и оценить количество элементов в массиве. Если один приметить flatten.